# How can I get the energy levels from a Hamiltonian?

Tags: energy

I'm helping out in a research project at my school and was tasked with plotting the magnetic field dependency (when B is parallel to each individual axis) of the energy levels of the molecule with which we're working.
I have the Hamiltonian from which I got all the eigenvalues (the computer did, it's a 216*216 matrix), I'm not sure where to go from there. (I have also calculated the free energy axis by axis at different temperatures, not sure if this will be useful, but I thought it might) I have to admit I'm pretty lost here. Do you guys have any insight?

Comment: I assume the program has calculated using some basis set the energy levels modified by the magnetic field. The eigenvectors are the states with the coresponding eigenvalues or energies.

Comment: I'm pretty lost :(, I haven't taken quantum yet, so a lot of this which is probably pretty obvious to others is not clear to me :/. I know that we did have a step, n, by which we increased the magnetic field and I can get different 216*216 matrices by changing the n value. The program then allows me to get the eigenvalues of the matrices. How would I use this information to make the plots? I'm just confused since for each value of n I get 216 different eigenvalues. Should I plot the n value in the x-axis and all the 216 values in the y-axis for each n? Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Hamiltonian should depend on the magnetic field so its eigenvalues also depend on the magnetic field. The energy levels you are looking for are those eigenvalues. The number of eigenvalues i.e. energy levels are determined by the basis you use and there are in your case 216 ones because your basis contains 216 vectors. Probably you only care for the occupied ones, which are the n lowest ones. n is the number of electrons you include in your calculation. The more basis vectors you use the more accurate your solution will be.

You now need to calculate the interesting eigenvalues for the magnetic field values you want to investigate and plot these. They should depend continiously on the magnetic field.